# How to Add or Remove Rows Based on Data in Column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was presented with a problem where static fields were being modified next to dynamic fields in a Google Spreadsheet. The issue being sometimes the column with dynamic data would change and the static fields would no longer apply to them.

I can't think of a way to handle this except for a script, but my scripting knowledge is limited at best.

The idea is to have a sheet that uses `=importrange()` that would house the dynamic data. Then a second sheet would have the static data which would have rows added or removed based on whether they match the dynamic sheet.

For example:

The dynamic sheet would be called "Source" and in the first column we would have the names: Peter, Brian, Louis, Chris, Stewie

The static sheet would be called "Target" and in the first column we would have the names: Peter, Brian, Louis, Chris, Meg

The idea would be to remove the row that has "Meg" in the first column and then insert a row (or add to the bottom of the range) the value of "Stewie".
End goal is to programmatically make the static list match the dynamic list.

Comment: I think that when there are a sample spreadsheet including the information of the current issue and the result you want, they will help users think of your solution.

Comment: This look like a requirement (asking a programmer to write a program) rather than a programming question (asking for help to write a program by yourself). Do you have a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After piecing together how I thought the process should go I was able to throw this together. I have two functions that get called by a third one. The first function is used to grab a 2d array of whichever sheet I need. The assumption here is the arrays that I'll be comparing to each other will all be in the first column.

```
function grabSheetInformation(sheet) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetInfo = ss.getSheetByName(sheet);
  var range = sheetInfo.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var rangeMax = range.filter(String).length;

  range = sheetInfo.getRange("A2:A" + (rangeMax + 1)).getValues();


  return range;

}
```

The second function that I use just sorts the data after everything is said and done.

```
function sortTargetData() {


  var sheetToSort = "Target"; // sheet name that is being sorted
  var columnToSortBy = 1; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var rangeToSort = "A2:R";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetToSort);
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeToSort);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
    }
```

This is where it all comes together.

```
function mergeData() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();



  var sourceInfo = grabSheetInformation("Source");
  var targetInfo = grabSheetInformation("Target");

  var sourceMax = sourceInfo.length;
  var targetMax = targetInfo.length;

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Target"));

  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var array = [];
  var offset = 1;


  for (var i = 0; i < targetMax; i++) {

  array.push(targetInfo[i][0]);
  }


  for (i = 0; i < sourceMax; i++) {

    if(array.indexOf(sourceInfo[i][0]) == -1) {

      sheet.insertRowAfter(targetMax + offset);

      sheet.getRange("A" + (targetMax + offset + 1)).setValue(sourceInfo[i][0]);


      offset++;

      }

  }

  // reset variables

  sourceInfo = grabSheetInformation("Source");
  targetInfo = grabSheetInformation("Target");

  sourceMax = sourceInfo.length;
  targetMax = targetInfo.length;

  sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  array = [];


  for (i = 0; i < sourceMax; i++) {

  array.push(sourceInfo[i][0]);
  }

  for (i = targetMax -1; i >= 0; i--) {

    if(array.indexOf(targetInfo[i][0]) == -1) {


      sheet.deleteRow(i+2);

      }

  }

sortTargetData();

}
```

As I posted in my initial question, the purpose of the script is to allow a user to have a dynamic list that they can add static values to.

The layout of the spreadsheet would have two tabs, "Source" and "Target". The "Source" tab would have the dynamic data in the first column with a header. For my use-case it would be pulled in using "=importrange()". The "Target" tab would have the first row contain headers and be updated via the script.

If there were values in the "Source" tab that weren't in the "Target" tab then rows would be added to the end of the list on the "Target" tab with the missing values added.

If there were values in the "Target" tab that weren't in the "Source" tab then the offending rows would be deleted.

My organization has multiple spreadsheets with employee names all over the place. The benefit of this would be to have a single list of names that can be updated and spreadsheets would automatically update with the most up-to-date list.

There is also the assumption that names won't be duplicated.

Spreadsheet that I created to test this out on:
[Shared View Only Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PaSJgBVjwLlbk6fJU7wsaKM4JBdSOJSETwbEE3b4V_k/edit?usp=sharing)